# How to rotate a rectangle drawn on canvas in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas, draw, rect

I am drawing a text on android canvas using the following piece of code

```
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
        canvas.translate(xPosition + position.getX(), yPosition + position.getY());
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(text_color);
        canvas.translate(-(xPosition + position.getX()), -(yPosition + position.getY()));
        canvas.rotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle), xPosition + position.getX() + rect.exactCenterX(), yPosition + position.getY() + rect.exactCenterY());
        canvas.drawText(text, xPosition + position.getX(), yPosition + position.getY(), paint);
```

This code takes care of the rotation of the text and it works fine. I am drawing a blue rectangle around the text using the above code. Now my problem is that the rectangle is not rotating along with the text. It still remains the same. Is there any way to rotate the rectangle drawn in android canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer. I used the following code

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
        paint.setColor(text_color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
        canvas.translate(xPosition + position.getX(), yPosition + position.getY());
        canvas.translate(-(xPosition + position.getX()), -(yPosition + position.getY()));
        canvas.rotate(getDegreesFromRadians(angle), xPosition + position.getX() + rect.exactCenterX(), yPosition + position.getY() + rect.exactCenterY());
        canvas.drawText(text, xPosition + position.getX(), yPosition + position.getY(), paint);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rect);
        canvas.translate(xPosition + position.getX(), yPosition + position.getY());
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        rect = new Rect(rect.left - 10, rect.top - 10, rect.right + 10, rect.bottom + 10);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

The thing is the whole canvas is being rotated for rotating the text. So i just need to draw the rectangle after the rotation of the canvas.

Comment: how did you calculate the angle , because i want to rotate a rect on user's touch basis

Comment: Hey @NirmalPrajapat I happened on your question and have a quick answer I can give you copied from work I have done previous, hope it is useful:

Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y - sdo.y, x - sdo.x)) + 40

...where x and y are the touch location (I used a drag handle overlay on the graphic), sdo is the bitmap being rotated and the x and y of that is the center of the bitmap, and the 40 constant is the angle where my drag handle is on top of the graphic, ie: the starting point.

Answer (score 10):

please use

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate();
//stuff to draw that should be rotated
canvas.restore();
```

else you have to compensate for every rotation afterwards